# Calculating Tax Based on Cart Subtotal in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, price, subtotal, tax

I want to calculate tax based on the entire cart subtotals. So in my case, if the `subtotal is < 1000`, the Tax need to be `5%` If the `subtotal is >=1000`, the Tax needs to be `12%`

I am having two classes `Reduced rate - 5%`, `Standard - 12%`

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_tax_class', 'wp_check_gst', 1, 2 );
    function wp_check_gst( $tax_class, $product ) 
    {
    
            $subtotal = 0;
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
                    $subtotal += $cart_item[ 'data' ]->get_price( 'edit' ) * $cart_item[ 'quantity' ];
                    
            }
            if ( $subtotal >= 1000 )
            {
                $tax_class = "Standard";
            }
            if ( $subtotal < 1000 )
            {
                $tax_class = "Reduced rate";
            }
        return $tax_class;
    }
```

I use this above code, which seems to be not working?? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook you are using is not the appropriate for the job. Since you want to modify the tax class which affects the basket totals you must use the hook `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`. Your code should be like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'tax_based_on_cart_subtotal', 10, 1 );
function tax_based_on_cart_subtotal( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    $subtotal = 0; 
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) { 
          $subtotal += $cart_item['line_total']; 
          }

    //Standard Tax 12%
    if ( $subtotal > 1000  ){
       // Change tax class for each cart ietm
       foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
          $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class( 'standard' );
       }
    }

    //Reduced rate Tax 5%
    if ( $subtotal < 1000  ){
       // Change tax class for each cart ietm
       foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
          $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class( 'reduced rate' );
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: $subtotal = 0; foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    $subtotal += $cart_item['line_total'];
    }.... I need to add this to make it to work

Comment: @musthafa thanks, changed the answer above. I'll test also my previous answer a bit better and come back if there is a way to make it work.